# Separating phone numbers and extensions from poorly formatted data in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of phone number strings.  I need to separate the number from the extension.  However, the formatting is obviously all over the place.  How would you best achieve this in PHP?

```
555-555-5555 ext 230
555-555-5555 ex 230
555-555-5555 x 230
555-555-5555 ext. 230
555-555-5555 ext230
555-555-5555 x230
555-555-5555 ext # 230`
```

I tried to use regex but I've not been able to come up with a pattern that matches everything above.

The phone numbers are also not exactly in good shape themselves.
Everything from `(555)555-555-5555` to `555 555-555-5555`.  Oh and some records have multiple numbers separated by words like `Mobile:`, `Cell:`, or a newline :D . But, that problem is for another question.

Also, extensions are not always 3 numbers.  Could be 2-4.

My expected result would be something along the lines of:

```
$array = [
    'phone' => '555-555-5555',
    'ext' => '123'
];
```

Comment: What would be your output?

Comment: Can you assume all phone numbers in the input data are in `555-555-5555` format? Will there be other formats like `(555)555-5555`?

Comment: @Raptor absolutely.  However, I'm mostly being held up by the extension separation at the moment.

Comment: I feel like the sample is not good enough to make an attempt. I bet there is always something in the phone number that will appear, "won't work because of one item is....".

Comment: @Andreas what would help you in terms of a better sample?

Comment: Actual samples (phone numbers can be masked of course). If you give us 10 items with all the same pattern that is what we will give you the answer on. I could just make an answer and say explode on first space. Is that correct? In your sample data it is. Does that make the answer correct? This is going to be a never ending rabbit hole. You are going to add to it all the time, just like you already have with new line and multiple phones in the same record.

Comment: Try this PHP library: https://github.com/brick/phonenumber

Answer (score 0):

Given the phone number is not f-ed up as well. You can do it like this:

```
$array = array (
    '555-555-5555 ext 230',
    '555-555-5555 ex 230',
    '555-555-5555 x 230',
    '555-555-5555 ext. 230',
    '555-555-5555 ext230',
    '555-555-5555 x230',
    '555-555-5555 ext # 230`',
);

$data = array();
foreach ($array as $val)
{
    while (!is_numeric(substr($val,-1))) {
        $val = substr_replace($val ,"", -1);
    }
    $data[] = array( 
            'num' => substr($val, 0, 12), 
            'ext' => substr($val, -3)
        );
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
```

Comment: This would work given my poor example, but phone numbers may not always be in that format.  And extensions may not always be 3 digits.  100% my bad when forming the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$number = "555-555-5555 ext 230";

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $number, $matches);

for($x=0;$x<count($matches);$x++){

        for($y=0;$y<count($matches[$x]);$y++){
            if($y == (count($matches[$x]) - 1)){
                    echo $matches[$x][$y];
                }else{
                    echo $matches[$x][$y]."-";

                }
        }
}

?>
```

result 555-555-5555-230 . btw, what is your expected result ?

Update . I don't know if this is best way, but please give a try

```
<?php
$number = "555-555-5555 x 230";

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $number, $matches);

for($x=0;$x<count($matches);$x++){

        for($y=0;$y<count($matches[$x]);$y++){
            if($y == (count($matches[$x]) - 1)){
                    $result[]= "#".$matches[$x][$y];
                }else{
                    $result[] = $matches[$x][$y];
                }
        }
}

    for($xy=0;$xy<count($result);$xy++){

        if($xy == count($result) - 1 ){
            $data['ext'][] = $result[$xy];
        }else{
            $data['number'][] = $result[$xy];
        }

    }

    $num = implode("-", $data['number']);
    $ext = implode("", str_replace("#","",$data['ext']));

    $final = array("number" => $num, "ext" => $ext);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($final);

?>
```

Comment: Added expected result example to my question.  My apologies.

Comment: @Gurnzbot you can check answer from ACD